# TV series about an ancient lost city in the jungle and their war with a secret desert cult

Tags: story-identification, tv

This TV Series was from the 80s or 90s, I was 6-7 when I was watching it, I think.

Two friends go on a parachuting trip and get lost in the jungle.
In the jungle, they get found by people from some long lost city.

1. City ruled by a young queen, who becomes sort of girlfriend with 1 of the boys
2. Together with them  a rogue pilot of a crashed plane.
3. The pilot assembles an army and tries to take over the city and is met by a fire-Throwing Tank.
4. He gets captured and send to a desert prison.
5. He escapes and goes fighting someone in the desert.
6. During his fight, a cloud of dust rises over horizon. Out of that cloud, comes a huge machine that looks like a very big iron.
7. Soldiers capture him and bring to the other place. Members of that place tried for centuries to conquer some hidden library that has ancient knowledge scroll know as 'The Source' or 'The Great Scroll'.
8. He goes with them to attack it and they repel their machine using a beam of focused sun rays emitted from a crystal.
9. He builds an airship and it also gets shot down by that beam.
10. Meanwhile, in the city here is some kind of plague. High Priestess who wants take throne from queen sabotages medicine to spark riot and depose queen to take her place.
11. Rogue pilot escapes after failed attack and steals some 3-wheleed bike.
    He rides in the desert. Bike runs out of what ever powers it and he has to walk back. Cult ruler puts him in jail. Jail has no door. When he comes in, flames spark out of holes in the floor blocking exit
12. Greedy High Priestess is found out. She escapes to desert and join cult leader in his quest to take over library

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [*Legend of the Hidden City*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0300795/) (1997).

> After surviving a helicopter crash in the uncharted South African
> wilderness, two young men, a girl and a renegade thief discover an
> ancient city unknown to civilization.

Comment: YOU GUYS ARE AMAZING!
Yes, that is the one. I hope I can find it. Very few places online stock old stuff.